Objective Function in Pyomo
I am running AC optimal power flow using pyomo. The objective function is to minimize the voltage deviations at all the buses.
def new_rule_V(model, k, s, t):
        total_V = 0
        if k != 'slack':
            V_nom = Bus_Vnom.loc[k, 'Vnom_pn']
            total_V = abs(model.V_mag_2[k, s, t]  - V_nom ** 2)
            #print(f"Constraint for x={total_V}")
            # total_V_1= total_V
        return total_V
        model.new_rule_V_f = pyo.Expression(model.Buses, model.Phases_abc, model.time,       rule=new_rule_V)

return sum(( model.new_rule_V_f[k, s, t])
             for k in model.Buses
             for s in model.Phases_abc
             for t in model.time)

model.obj = pyo.Objective(rule=Objective_rule,sense=pyo.minimize) 

Is it correct method to define objective function? The code runs until maximum iteration limit  exceeds. max limit is 100000.

There is not enough information to reproduce the problem. But abs() is non-differentiable, which can be a problem for many NLP solvers.

Thanks a lot @Erwin Kalvelagen, the problem is solved.
